# Has there ever been a "strike-em-out-throw-2-out" triple play?

Tags: baseball, trivia

Has there ever been a "strike-em-out-throw-2-out" triple play?

(I started wondering that after watching this YouTube video [MLB | Strike 'em Out, Throw 'em Out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szhkOx2OE3w).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Has there ever been a "strike-em-out-throw-2-out" triple play?

Yes.

---

In collegiate baseball, Indiana University accomplished this on May 29, 2015.

Sources:

- [Tweet from NCAA college world series](https://twitter.com/NCAACWS/status/604369337600745473)
- [Article](https://sports.yahoo.com/blogs/mlb-big-league-stew/indiana-records-strike-em-out--throw-em-out--throw-em-out-again-triple-play-164503070.html)

Also in collegiate baseball, New Mexico Junior College accomplished this on March 10, 2015.

Sources:

- [Article](http://m.mlb.com/atbat/cutfour/2015/03/10/112018320/video-new-mexico-junior-college-strike-em-out-throw-em-out-triple-play)
- [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QGCpbUaEII)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there has.  This one involved a strike out, caught stealing at second, and caught stealing at home.  Effectively, strike out and 2-4-2 on the scoring.   I’m not sure of the level in the [following video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yqde2sPMLNw).  It’s a bit grainy and looks to be either minor league or college.

Comment: Details would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

Just saw a 2-3-2-5 triple play, manly representative play, bankstown, nsw, no outs, runners 2nd/ 3rd, dropped third strike, out at first, then home, then third! Easy as!

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. Can you provide a reference to a credible score source for this event? It would also help to establish the level of play - it's not entirely clear why this is notable.